# How to remove / hide instructions from magento shipping lable (Fedex , USPS)

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods, admin-panel, labels

I dont want that `instructions` in `shipping lable`, So please kindly help to achieve this.

[image]

[image]

I dont want any message after the line. like

> "For FedEx"
>
> `"After Printing this lable"`
>
> `"Warning"`
>
> "For USPS"
>
> `"Instructions`

Comment: do you have ssh access ? or else you need to search for those texts and remove them....

Comment: no @BabyinMagento it is comming from API

Comment: @MineshPatel oh, Thanks for nice information buddy....

Comment: @BabyinMagento added  description

Comment: So we cant remove that words from my label right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am familiar with UPS and DHL but not sure about FedEx and USPS, but I am sure that label API should contain some options for shipping label layout and size same as UPS and DHL

For Fedex check file

> app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php

method

> _formShipmentRequest()

check below option

```
'LabelSpecification' =>array(
       'LabelFormatType' => 'COMMON2D',
       'ImageType' => 'PNG',
       'LabelStockType' => 'PAPER_8.5X11_TOP_HALF_LABEL',
 ),
```

check API documentation for same and try it out.

same should apply for USPS in file

> app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Minesh, I will tried this with 'LabelStockType' => 'PAPER_4X6'. but no luck.

Comment: you need to try with all possible options. i am assuming it should have option to not include Warning and Instructions on labels

Comment: Yeah sure @Minesh. I googled and find other types too. if you know any types please let me know. it would help to me :)

Comment: check [this](https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/WebHelp/fsms/1501/html/FSMSHelp/FSMSTWN/5_Label_Changes.htm)

Comment: or you can write mail to support team with your user details with requirement they will provide you options if available

Comment: I used all that types but i getting like this error message "Invalid values in Label Stock Type for LABEL; Shipper Postal-City Mismatch; Origin Location-Postal Mismatch.;" Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: no just write down mail to support team of fexed and usps

Comment: https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/WebHelp/ws/2014/dvg/WS_DVG_WebHelp/13_3_2_Generating_a_Laser_Label.htm

Comment: i used that links for update the values